# How do I prevent the "Could Not Find" error message from del *.txt?

Tags: batch-file

In a Windows batch-file, this line:

```
del *.txt
```

Will give the error/warning message:

```
Could Not Find C:\*.txt
```

if there are no files matching the pattern *.txt. Is there a way to prevent that message?

Answer (score 44):

```
if exist *.txt del *.txt
```

Answer (score 36):

If you want to suppress **all** error messages, you can do this:

```
del *.txt 2>NUL
```

Comment: What is that `2`? Why `del *.txt >NUL` doesn't work?

Comment: @nrofis: It redirects the error output, rather than the standard output.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams for the numbering.

Comment: The disadvantage of this method is that if there is a real error, such as the files are locked then that message will be swallowed. Personally, I prefer @peterchen's if exist approach.

Answer (score 4):

surround with an if exists...

or use a different delete utility {like 'rm' from the mks tools}

or take a look at forfiles.exe - that should do what you need.

Answer (score -1):

Create one.

```
echo "Moo" > temporary-del-workaround.txt
```

Your removed file count will be off-by-one though.

**edit**:

- `NUL` redirect answer is wrong because there can be real errors.
- `exists` answer is suboptimal because it does the work twice and if you've filled your directory with 60K+ files, the simple listing will easily be as long as removal

Comment: *Create one.* Great (and funny) answer! :-D